# SQL get average of counted grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the average amount of posts per day using SQL

Here is my query, right now it is only getting the amount of posts per day. How can I change it so that it just gives the average of all posts per day?
`SELECT count(*) as totalPosts, Date(createdAt) from Post GROUP BY Date(createdAt)`

example output:

```
totalPosts       Date(createdAt)
2342               2016-12-14
4252               2016-12-15
4232               2016-12-16
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The query I posted lists off the amount of posts per day. I just want the average of all days (posts per day)

Comment: It's confusing because the output only shows 1 date...

Comment: Yup sorry I should have included more dates, my query outputs a list, but I want the average of totalPosts

Comment: `SELECT avg(amount) FROM (SELECT count(*) as amount, createdAt FROM Post GROUP BY createdAt) as A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just stick your existing query in a subquery and grab the average:

```
SELECT AVG(totalPosts) as avgPostsPerDay
FROM (SELECT count(*) as totalPosts, Date(createdAt) from Post GROUP BY Date(createdAt)) dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use division without a subquery:

```
SELECT count(*) / count(distinct Date(createdAt))
from Post;
```